# Load Picture to Microsoft Access 2010 Ribbon from Table

Tags: image, bitmap, ms-access-2010, ribbon

I'm working with Access 2010's new ribbon feature, and I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to load an image to the ribbon from a table. I know that I could do this by using a GDI API function, but from what I can see the code looks convoluted and appears to utilize extra dlls that I would just as well avoid calling if I don't need to. I also know that I could create a control on a form, load the image to the form, and then load the image from the form to the ribbon image variable. While using the form is doable, it seems sloppy. Eventually, I will resort to one of the two preceding methods if I have to, but it just seems like there should be some simple way to load an image from a table directly into an image variable for the ribbon.

One thing to note is that I'm willing to use whatever image format is easiest. These icon files are very small and so I'm not concerned about file size and I also don't care whether or not they are capable of transparency. So if there's a method that only works with bitmap file types that is fine with me.

Here's the code I have for the button in the ribbon XML:

```
<button id="CCTrans" label="Credit Card Trans." getImage="GetMnuIcn" onAction="=OpenCCTrans()" />
```

And here's the code I have for retrieving the image:

```
Sub GetMnuIcn(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Image)
    Set Image = DLookup("Img", "LtblImg", "Lbl=""" & control.ID & """")
End Sub
```

I've tried storing the image both as an OLE Object and as an attachment. Either way, when I try to retrieve it, it gives me the error "Type Mismatch". For simplicity, I've been storing it as a bitmap, but I also tried .gif and .png in my first attempts.

Note: Apparently the ribbon icons are IPictureDisp objects. If I can just figure out how to load an image from a table into one of those object types, I should be able to use it for the ribbon.

Also, there's a lot of good information on Microsoft's website, but I haven't been able to piece it together into a solution yet. Here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb187398.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after tedious days of trying to find a better solution, I'm forced to pick between what I feel are various mediocre approaches. I really wanted to just load it directly into a variable, but the only method for doing that requires references to a bunch of dlls and has code that is pretty complicated. To avoid any extra dependencies and to keep my code simpler, I decided to go the route of assigning the table containing the attached images to a form, opening that form in hidden mode and then assigning the picture variables from the form.

For some reason the code that I saw elsewhere that loaded the pictures on demand via this method caused my program to crash and so I had to load the pictures into variables when the program opened and then have the menu bar set the icons from those variables when the menu is selected.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim Icn(15) As IPictureDisp, IcnLbl(15) As String   

Function SetMnuIcn()
    Dim Img As Recordset, i As Byte
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmImg", acNormal, , , acFormReadOnly, acHidden  
    Set Img = Forms!frmImg.Recordset
    While Not Img.EOF
        i = i + 1
        Set Icn(i) = Forms!frmImg!Img.PictureDisp
        IcnLbl(i) = Img!Lbl
        Img.MoveNext
    Wend
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmImg", acSaveNo
End Function

Sub GetMnuIcn(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Image)
    Set Image = Icn(GetAryLoc(IcnLbl, control.ID, 15))
End Sub

Function GetAryLoc(varValues As Variant, varMatch As Variant, NumOfValues As Integer) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To NumOfValues
        If varValues(i) = varMatch Then GetAryLoc = i
    Next
End Function
```

Note: To ensure that the icons have been loaded prior to when they are needed, I specified SetMnuIcn to run on ribbon load:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="=SetMnuIcn()">
```